# How do I disable a locking door latch?

Tags: lock

I have the following door handle / lock combination that leads out to my garage. The key for the door has long been lost and sometimes someone will turn the internal lock and the door cannot be opened from the garage side. I wish to disable this lock, how do I do that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you just replace the knob with a non-locking version of the same shape and style?

Comment: I could be that would require a lot more effort and cost and is currently plan B. If I could disable this lock that would be the best solution. +1 for suggestion though as it is certainly valid.

Comment: Do you know the manufacturer of the handle?

Comment: I thought this was a home *improvement* site? I'd get a new lock with a new set of keys. You're going to need to spend the money one day when you sell the home, why not enjoy the benefit of it while you live there.

Comment: Replacing the handle would not be MORE effort than what you want to do.  Replacing the handle would take removing two screws, pulling the handle apart, and inserting the new one and putting two screws back in.  It would cost you about $30 to "do it right".

Comment: I don't get why so many people focus on installing a new thing. The OP is ready to toy with his current lock and spend time on that and he asks a specific question on what can be done. I'm pretty sure he knows he can buy a new one and I'm pretty sure it was his sane decision to first try adjust the lock. Why so much focus on "spend this sum of money and forget about your idea"?

Comment: A big box store will sell a non-locking knob for under $20. If time is money, then it's often the best option. For a super-simple option, stick some super glue into the lock tab so it can't turn.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk I used superglue.

Comment: Please provide and accept an answer so the question can be resolved.

Comment: take the handle to a locksmith and have a key made

Answer (score 9):

Glue could fail and/or look ugly. Other options cost money. When you remove the inside knob, you will see a connecting rod protruding from the latch mechanism that engages the lock button. Cut this off so it no longer engages the lock button. Do not cut the semi circular shaft that engages the main lever! Ensure the remaining stub is turned to the unlock position and reassemble the knob. The lock button will now turn freely, but it's impossible to lock the knob without a key or disassembling the knob.

Comment: Just did this at home and it worked great. Mine did not have a semicircular shaft on the back of the handle, but did have a small (~5mm x 2mm) connecting rod. Works just as described (lock button turns freely, exterior locking works as before).

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to take the lock to a locksmith and have it re-keyed to a new key (and get a bunch of copies of that key). I have heard that this can cost less than the cost of a new doorknob.

However, as this would involve removing the knob and taking it the locksmith, I would probably just get a new knob and replace it (unless you really like the style/color/etc of the current one).

Comment: Pretty sure this costs more than a cheap new knob almost anywhere.  Also not answering his question.

Comment: @DMoore I guess it depends on how close friends you are with the locksmith? It depends on how nice a knob you want too. OP said he lost the keys so I wanted to offer an alternative.

Comment: I'm very late here, but if you have a Menards close they'll rekey just about any lock for around $4. (Doesn't answer OP's question, but may help others)

Comment: Home Depot usually charges $5 per lock core rekeying. I believe they take kits like this one and just permute the colored pins to the desired combination. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Kwikset-Rekeying-Kit-for-5-or-6-Pin-Cylinder-272-KEYING-KIT/100637468

Answer (score 6):

First, unlock the door.  Now place a piece of tape across the small knob you use to lock/unlock the door so that it doesn't move.  Next, take off the handle and glue the knob in place so that it cannot be operated.  Re-install the handle.

Comment: What if I just put some superglue into the gap around that small knob when it's in the unlocked position without disassembling the lock?

Comment: I'm sure that would work too, I just figured you'd get better looking results if you did it from inside the lock instead of outside

Comment: Does this door allow access to your home from the garage?If it does, not only do you want it  the lock to work but you want to use it. Automatic door openers are not the most secure system. A thief can access your garage  and walk in to your house via the inside door.

Comment: @mikes - both the automatic garage door and the internal door are alarmed. I figured that if someone were to open the garage door then that alarm would trigger and putting another obstacle in their way (i.e. another door lock) wasn't going to help much after that.

Comment: @Guy Bear in mind an alarm does not actually stop a thief or vandal, it might only scare them (or not). And if the alarm is not monitored, it provides no protection when you are away. Just some thoughts.

Comment: Keep in mind that at that point the thief is hidden from your neighbors' view inside your garage, and maybe even can borrow some of your tools stored there to work on the door. If you really care then install a deadbolt, but even then, it will slow down but not stop a determined thief.

Answer (score 5):

I have a residential Family Care Home and the state requires that a business such as this have doors throughout the home that will not lock regardless of whether it has a locking mechanism. I could have gone out and purchased the ones that won't lock,but they cost almost $40 a piece (I needed 6), so I placed a magnetic metal strip over the door jamb to prevent the door from locking, and the door still closes perfectly. Ace, Home Depot, and Lowe's stock these strips, and most hardware stores will cut them to your specifications for less than $2 a piece.  This way if you decide to sell the home, you simply remove the strips.

Doing this saved me a lot of money, and it works!

Answer (score 5):

[image]I had the same problem, different keys for the bolt lock and the knob. In the picture I show what I cut on my knob to keep it from ever locking. You may find that your center post looks more like a flat bar but it does the same thing and will need to be cut.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the handle take the lock apart and remove the pins. You could also bring the handle into a hardware store that cuts keys and get a set of keys made or you can get the lock re keyed to work with your front door key or another.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple, subtle and reversible solution is to put something in the frame-side slot. I had a similar problem and found it was trivial to cut the leftover cork from a wine bottle to fit in the slot where the bolt would otherwise automatically spring-load in. So, now, even if someone pushes in the door handle lock button, the bolt remains retracted and the door opens easily.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by removing the knob side of the handle and then driving the knob out hitting it very gently. A hammer and a small diameter socket will do

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question...